# Error on instantiating a SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET and C# to create a website in Visual Studio 2010. I have seen examples where others convert what they have stored in a database, into a List to be able to work with it better. However, I chose to  attach an SqlDataSource into a CheckBoxList instead and I'm using the SqlDataSource in my C# code so that I can query into the database. This gives me an error:

```
 protected void BrandList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //Connecting to the database: Error here
      using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ProductNameDS)) 

      //Loop through the checkbox
      foreach (ListItem product in BrandList.Items)
      {

           //If product is selected, return that item from the database to the
           //user

           if (product.Selected.Equals(Toshiba)
           {
                return (from c in context.Products
                     where c.Name Like 'Toshiba%'
                     select c.Name); 
           }
```

The error that I get for the SqlDataSource is an overload error. What can I do to fix this and connect to my data source?

Comment: Can you post the actual error? The issue appears to be that 'SqlDataSource' takes either 3 or 2 or no arguments and yet you are passing only 1 argument. Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also consider using braces after the `using` statement for better readability.

Comment: How is `ds` related to the code that follows? Shouldn't the code rather involve the `context` somehow?

Comment: The error is 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. I should also mention that the "ProductNameDS" parameter is the name of the SqlDataSource I attached to the CheckBoxList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned the constructor does not take 1 argument see the documentation in the link below. It is expecting a connection string and a select command.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx